# Codes and question mark Conversion in HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp

So i'm having a problem where I'm using JSP.

I send a code to the HTML page and the page converts parts of the code into "?"

The code that im sending to the HTML page:

```
"assertEquals('\uD83D\uDE30\', StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv('\uD83D\uDE30\'));",
```

How it is showed in the html page:

```
assertEquals("?", StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv("?"));
```

So, I want to keep the code and do not parse it to "?" 
Anyone knows how to do that ?

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue!! You may have to create an array of your `\u` values, and send that to the page and then let the browser (javascript) convert them to characters, and then reconstruct your assert statement.

Comment: no @Pikamander2 it does not =/

Comment: The double byte sequence decodes to "" (http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=). Maybe the font in your "showed in the html page" just doesn't contain that character.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to print the string

```
assertEquals('\uD83D\uDE30\', StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv('\uD83D\uDE30\'));
```

as it is on the web page.

Below code produces the incorrect output as you have given in your question

```
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.print("assertEquals('\uD83D\uDE30\', StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv('\uD83D\uDE30\'));");
```

But adding one more extra to above "\" prints the correct output

```
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.print("assertEquals('\\uD83D\\uDE30\\', StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv('\\uD83D\\uDE30\\'));");
```

"\u" is a unicode escape, while "\u" is not.

In my opinion 
while printing, printer is considering \uD83D as unicode 
char and tries to decode it, and when it is unable to do so prints "?".

When you add extra "\",  \uD83D becomes a simple string and gets printed as it is.